# Master Detail Sharing Rule

Tags: sharing, master-detail

I know that Details inherits Masters permissions but i am bit confused with the below scenario -

```
Object A - Master Object and profile has Create/Edit/Delete/View all on it

Object B - Detail Object and profile has Create/Edit/Delete on it.

Now Users X comes and create Object A record with above profile. 
User X and Y have same level role so record can't be accessed using role hierarchy.

Now i create a Permission set XXX with permission Create/Edit/Delete/View All/Modify All
on Object B and assign this permission set to User Y.

Now User Y open the detail page of Object A created by User A(As profile has View all    
Permission on object A) and create Object B and try to save it -

1) Will he be able to save Object B As permission set grant him Modify all on Object B?
2) Will he get an Exception as he doesn't have Edit permission on Object A and Object A 
   and B has Master detail relationship?
3) Will he get an Edit permission on Object A(Master Object) since permission set grants 
   him Modify all on Object B(Detail Object.)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1) yes
2) no
3) no

Did you try this out, by the way? There might be even other factors influencing the outcome. The sharing button can be of great help in these complex setups.